# Is there anyway to get a variable from previous filter in Yii2?

Tags: filter, yii, yii2, middleware

In Yii2.0, I want to get a value from previous filter to avoid make the same query in every filter .
Is there anyway to make it ?

For example , this is my code in a controller :

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'filter1' => ['class' => Filter1::className()],
        'filter2' => ['class' => Filter2::className()]
    ];
}
```

In `filter1` , I make a sql query, and I want use the result of this query in `filter2` because I don't want make this query again.
How should I do ?
And if I want get a value from a filter in my controller, how should I do ?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to make two filters depending on each other unless it's really necessary. If you are afraid of performance you can cache the result of the query.

Comment: This is good, I would take this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you would be coupling your behaviors - you could access any behaviour through the component it is attached to

```
\Yii::$app->controller->getBehavior('filter1')->yourValue
```

or from filter2 behaviour:

```
$this->owner->getBehaviour('filter1')->yourValue
```

See

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-behavior.html#$owner-detail